# JavaScript dropdown menu not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add active class by using JS but seems not working.

Here is the code

```
 <ul id="menuList">
    <li class="menu">
      <a href="home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <ul id="hm">
     <li>
       <a  href="#">home01</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
   <li class="menu">
      <a href="gallery">gallery</a>
   </li>
  <li class="menu">
     <a href="about">about</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu">
     <a href="contact">contact</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: post a jsfiddle of your code. And try to indent your code so we can view it easier.

Comment: What is the output vs expected output?

Comment: Gonna need to see the JS as well. Try jsfiddle.net

Comment: You close `<ul>` to early

Comment: Sorry link broken, here is jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/uhjwpvs0/37/

Comment: Output should be normal - while click on home. it should show me sub menu.  but its not taking active class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** Try this

```js
var flag = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menuList li:not(:first-child)').click(function(){
    $('li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('#hm').css("display", "none");
    $('#hm').css("list-style", "none");
    flag = 1;
});
$('#menuList > li:first-child').click(function(){
  $('li').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  if(flag == 1){
    $('#hm').css("display", "block");
    $('#hm').css("list-style", "square");
    flag = 0;
  } else {
    $('#hm').css("display", "none");
    $('#hm').css("list-style", "none");
    flag = 1;
  }
});
});
```

```css
.active
{
  display:block;
    background-color:green;
}
 #hm{
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menuList">
<li class="menu active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <ul id="hm">
 <li><a href="#">home01</a></li>
 </ul>
<li class="menu"><a href="#gallery">gallery</a></li>
<li class="menu"><a href="#about">about</a></li>
<li class="menu"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Md for reply, But buddy Home taking background color green but not showing submenu.

Comment: It's Working Nasir, Thanks for a big help.  Appreciated

Comment: Ohh sorry for that, i m new bee for stack overflow.  so did it now, and can you help me with similar issues?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I will if I get time

Comment: Ok buddy,  Whenever you get time, just reply me here. will tell you.

Comment: Thanks. But I think It will be better to ask a question in stackoverflow, because there will be more expert to answer your question. :)